# jQuery simple function wont work

Tags: jquery

Why wont an alert box pop up when happen when I 'Click me'?

Im a total noob at javascript/jquery but im trying to learn a bit I just found this example in a tutorial but it wont work

Look: http://*removed*

edit: removed my site link since question is solved

Comment: good question xD didnt say anything about having to load it in the tutorial :/ but now i know

Comment: i updated the question with link to my site instead so you can see it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to put your code inside $(document).ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("Hi");
        return false;
    })
});
```

Otherwise the code won't be properly bound to the event, since it will try to bind it when the page still hasn't loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `false` from the click handler or the page might get redirected:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
    return false;
});
```

Also don't forget to include jQuery in the `head` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You only need `return false;` if you have your jQuery in the HTML code, right?